# Show few countries on jVectormap

Tags: jquery, maps, jvectormap

I am using jVectormap, My client has offices in USA, Italy and France. Is there a way to show only these countries on the map and still use markers to show the office locations?

My UI prototype shows US in a large area and in small area on the right shows Italy and france map in a box. I need to use markers to display office information on the markers. I am open to ideas and suggestions. An example of jsFiddle will be of great help to the stackoverflow community.

Comment: Not quite sure what you want. Do you want all 3 countries on the same map or 3 separate maps of single countries?

Comment: Sorry.. for replying late.. I want all the 3 countries on the same map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It `could` be something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xZ28/168/).

Comment: Thank you. This is great. I may not want alaska but need to include hawaii. I will play with jsFiddle and this is a good start for me.

Comment: the jsfiddle is no longer there, maybe the answer details could also be added here?